# Right align background image

Tags: css, reactjs, native

I am trying to achieve the same effect with React Native:

```
{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: center right no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(/static/media/background.png);
}
```

So far I can make the image align to the center of the screen, but not at right (because can't use the same properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this first
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction

The `float` property doesn't exist in React Native, but there are loads of options available to you (with slightly different behaviors) that will let you right-align your text/Image(Read the doc link above).

Now lets come back to your answer.
You can directly specify the item's alignment, for example :

```
textright: {    
  alignSelf: 'flex-end',  
},
```

Comment: Does not work the same way on react-native-web, but it works on mobile, which is good enough